# Null set of Bernoulli distribution

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have an assignment in which I am supposed to determine the null set of the Bernoulli distribution w.r.t. the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. Specifically:

Let $(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{B},P)$ be a measure space, where $\mathscr{B}$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ and $P$ the probability measure Bernoulli distribution i.e. P is characterized by $$P\left(\{0\}\right)=p,\quad P(\{1\})=1-p,\quad 0<p<1$$
Determine $N_P=\{N\subseteq\mathbb{R}| \text{There exists $A\in \mathscr{B}$ so $N\subseteq A$ and $P(A)=0$}\}$

I don't what to do. I don't understand how the Bernoulli distribution is defined on $\mathscr{B}$. How would you evaluate any open interval on the real number line for example.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

For $\ A\in\mathscr{B}\ $, $\ P(A)\ $ must have one of four values:
$$
P(A)=\cases{0&if $\ 0\not\in A$ and $\ 1\not\in A$\\
p&if $\ 0\in A\ $ but $\ 1\not\in A$\\
1-p&if $\ 1\in A\ $ but $\ 0\not\in A$\\
1&if $\ 0\in A\ $ and $\ 1\in A\ $.}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If $N$ is a null set and $M\subseteq N$ then also $M$ is a null set.

Now be aware that  $\{0,1\}^{\complement}$ is evidently the largest null set in this context.